# Adding diagonal lines to a GridHelper object in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

First image is what I want. (I even want the opposite diagonal too, but I will derive that accordingly.) Second image is a normal `GridHelper`.

[image: First image is what I want. (I even want the opposite diagonal too) Second image is a normal GridHelper]

Would this be possible by adding another grid helper but rotated along the y-axis by 45 degrees?

I cannot seem to find anything in the [official docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/helpers/GridHelper), so I am assuming that there is an alternate approach. Any pointers on how this could be done?

My code for the `GridHelper`:

```
grid = new THREE.GridHelper(80, 15, 0x000000, 0x000000);
grid.position.y = -0.2;
scene.add(grid);
```

I am thinking that a possible solution may lie in `EdgesGeometry`. I am still  unsure about how to proceed with this, since:

```
EdgesGeometry( geometry, thresholdAngle )
```

Where `geometry` is any geometry object.

Does the `GridHelper` count as a geometry object? Here are the [official docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/EdgesGeometry).

***EDIT:***
Here is a visual example of my current situation: [codepen example](https://codepen.io/Riz2o/pen/wPpYxb).

Comment: Why not to use a mesh with `THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry()` and, for example, `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()` with `wireframe: true`?

Comment: If possible I would like to keep the `GridHelper`'s properties, such that objects may only be added to the grid lines. I will try your suggested method and see how it goes, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using of `THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry()` and a material with `wireframe: true` will give you the desired result.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 50, 25);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var gridGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(80, 80, 15, 15);
gridGeometry.rotateY(Math.PI);
gridGeometry.rotateX(-Math.PI * .5);
var gridMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "black",
  wireframe: true
});
var gridWithDiagonals = new THREE.Mesh(gridGeometry, gridMaterial);
scene.add(gridWithDiagonals);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```